# Fetch signedJwt token for google service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, impersonation, service-accounts, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I am trying to generate signedJWT token for google service account

```
now = int(time.time())
expires = now + 900  # 15 mins in seconds, can't be longer.
payload = {
     'iat': now,
     'exp': expires,
     'sub': 'somekey@someproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
     'aud': 'aud'
}
body = {'payload': json.dumps(payload)}
name = 'projects/someproject/serviceAccounts/somekey@someproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com'

iam = googleapiclient.discovery.build('iam', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
request = iam.projects().serviceAccounts().signJwt(name=name, body=body)
resp = request.execute()
jwt = resp['signedJwt']
```

The problem I am facing is regarding credentials
If I use

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(gcp_json_credentials_dict)
```

works fine.

But I am trying to use default service account

```
credentials, your_project_id = google.auth.default(scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"])
```

Getting following error -

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://iam.googleapis.com/v1/projects/someproject/serviceAccounts/somekey@someproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com:signJwt?alt=json returned "Permission iam.serviceAccounts.signJwt is required to perform this operation on service account
```

Comment: Are you certain that the default service account used does in fact have the iam.serviceAccounts.signJwt  permission? You can check the sa email with credentials.service_account_email to confirm that the default credentials is the SA that you expect.

Comment: it returns "default"

Answer (score 5):

First, I will try to explain why you are getting the error:

**permission iam.serviceAccounts.signJwt is required to perform this operation on service account**.

A) Your code is running on a compute service using the default service account. I will call this **Identity-1**.

B) Your code is impersonating the identity **somekey@someproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com**. I will call this **Identity-2**.

Your code needs permissions to use the credentials of **Identity-1** and the rights to impersonate **Identity-2**.

**Part 1:**

When you use the default service account for a compute service or assign a service account to a compute service, two forms of permission control are in effect. The master control is the **IAM roles** assigned to the service account. The limiter is the ** OAuth scopes** set for the compute service.

The OAuth scopes do not grant permissions, the OAuth scopes limit permissions already granted to the service account via IAM roles. This is an important point that I see so many configure incorrectly. I recommend using the compute engine **Access scopes** set to **Allow full access to all Cloud APIs**. Then modify/manage the IAM roles assigned to the service account assigned to Compute Engine.

**Part 2:**

In order to impersonate another identity, in your case **Identity-1** is impersonating **Identity-2**, your code must have the right to do so. There are two types of identities that can be impersonated: a) service accounts; b) user identities. In your case, you are impersonating another service account.

If you are impersonating a service account, that requires granting the correct IAM permission via an IAM role on **Identity-2** with the member set to **Identity-1**. Think of it this way: **Identity-2** must grant permission to **Identity-1**.

If you are impersonating a user identity, that requires setting up Google Workspace **Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority**. The account that you are impersonating must be managed by Google Workspace. Refer to [Google Workspace Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) is set up user account impersonation which is not required in your case.

Now you might wonder, which identity needs the right to impersonate? The identity that the JWT represents. That identity is declared by the JWT claim **iss**. **Your JWT does not include an iss claim**. For more details an example see this [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account). The identity that you are impersonating is specified by the claim **sub**. In OAuth speak **iss** is impersonating **sub**.

**Part 3:**

You must also configure your Google Cloud Project to support your objective. This requires enabling two APIs:

- iamcredentials.googleapis.com
- cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com

**Solution:**

1. Enable the required APIs:

`gcloud services enable iamcredentials.googleapis.com`

`gcloud services enable cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com`

2. Set the Compute Engine **Access Scopes** to **Allow full access to all Cloud APIs**. This requires shutting down the VM and editing the VM configuration.
3. Add the **iss** claim to the JWT that you are creating with the value **Identity-1**.
4. Grant an IAM Role containing the permission **iam.serviceAccounts.signJwt**. A good role to use is **Service Account Token Creator** to Identity-2. See this [link](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#service-accounts-roles) for more details.

Example command:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding [Identity-2] \
--member serviceAccount:[Identity-1\ \
--role roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator
```